# Task.Wait() doesn't include any chained (ContinueWith) tasks

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

If you have

```
Private Shared Sub msg(Optional message As String = "")
    Debug.WriteLine(Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId & " " & message)
End Sub
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub TestMethod1()
    Dim cancel As New Threading.CancellationTokenSource
    msg("starting")
    Dim start As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim task As New Task(Sub()
                             msg("in thread")
                             Do Until Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds > 2000
                                 Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                                 msg("loop")
                                 cancel.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                             Loop
                         End Sub, cancel.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
    task.ContinueWith(Sub(result As task)
                          msg("Continue task running")
                          Debug.WriteLine(result.Status.ToString & If(result.Exception Is Nothing, ", no exception", ", exception occurred " & result.Exception.GetType.Name))
                          Do Until Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds > 10000
                              cancel.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                              Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                              msg("innerloop")
                          Loop
                      End Sub)
    task.Start()
    Try
        If Not task.Wait(4000, cancel.Token) Then
            msg("wait expired, time to cancel)")
            cancel.Cancel()
        End If
        task.Wait()

    Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
        msg("task was cancelled")
    Finally
        msg("finishing")
    End Try
End Sub
```

The question is when I do task.Wait(4000, cancel.Token) this should ultimately fail as the ContinueWith task won't complete within the timeout.

It seems the Wait only applies to the Task and doesn't take the chain into account, how can I have it wait until the "chain" is complete?

Comment: Why should it take the chain into account? That's not how tasks work.

Answer (score 7):

Wait on the task returned by the ContinueWith function.

Comment: The problem with waiting on the Task returned by ContinueWith is that the Task hasn't started at that point, until when the running task is finished. So it doesn't actually Wait. Must admit I haven't tried WaitAll including both tasks, your thoughts?

Comment: I meant store the continuation task and wait on it after you start the initial task. You might also consider using the more convenient Task.Factory.StartNew instead of creating a new task and starting it later, because it avoids this type of issue.